# How to linebreak part ToC entries using tocloft/titletoc and the book class

Tags: table-of-contents, line-breaking, tocloft, parts, titletoc

I'm currently writing a LaTeX document in the book documentclass. In my ToC I want the actual titles of certain entries (parts in my case) to come in a newline after a generic name of the section-type ('Part') followed by the number ('I', 'II', ...), so it should look like this:

> Part I
>
> Title of first part
>
> Part II
>
> Title of second part

I'm using the tocloft package to customize the ToC and its manual actually has an example that excactly describes how to achieve this. Apparently, for whatever reason, the newline command (see MWE) has no effect with the book class. Any suggestions on what is the problem here?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{\partname\ }
\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnumb}{\\ }
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \part{Title of first part}
  \part{Title of second part}
\end{document}
```

EDIT 1:
I've followed @locksteps advice and tried to implement a solution with the `titletoc`package. However, now I'm stuck with the problem that for part entries for whatever reason the lablenummer is always attached to the actual title, for chapter and so on one can call the label independently

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{part}[0pt]{}{}{\Large\bfseries Part\\*}{}[]
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{}{Chapter \thecontentslabel\\*}{}{}[]
\begin{document}
   \tableofcontents
   \part{The first part}
   \chapter{The first chapter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

`tocloft`s `\cftXaftersnumb` macro family doesn't work for `X` = `part` in the `book` class. Quoting from the `tocloft` manual, p. 9:

> In the standard classes the ToC entry for a `\part` is just typeset as
>   the number and title, followed by the page number, with the
>   `\cftpartpresnum` macro being called before typesetting the number and
>   title. When a standard class is used the `\cftpartaftersnum` and
>   `\cftpartaftersnumb` macros have no effect, but they may do something
>   if a non-standard class is used.

Comment: Oh...I missed this one completly, explains a lot. I guess there is no 'easy' workaround?

Comment: @PaulHanson: Probably not (though I'd like to be proved wrong). Have a look at the `titletoc` package.

Comment: I've played around with titletoc but without success, see my edited question

Comment: If you prefer to use the ``tocloft`` package, you might try using the ``KOMA`` ``scrbook`` class and/or ``titlesec`` as I suggested in my answer.  This might be enough to get ``\cftpartaftersnum`` and ``\cftpartaftersnumb`` back into the game.

Comment: I tried ``scrbook`` with your MWE and it seems to work, but I find the formatting of ``tocloft`` very confusing.  In this case ``\cftpartpresnum`` is actually expanded twice, so you end up with "Part Part I".  Not sure exactly how to fix this. I find the ``titletoc`` package quite explicit and predictable, so generally use this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the way the standard classes send information to the ToC is different for parts and chapters.  This is discussed in the `titletoc` documentation: To get a consistent behaviour for parts you need to redefine the `\part` command.

One way is to use a different document class like the `KOMA` scripts `scrbook`.  Another is to use the `titlesec` package with the **newparttoc** option and issue one of the commands that redefines `\part` (like `\titleformat`).  The second option is shown below in the commented region:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

% If you really want the standard book class, uncomment the following:
%\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}
%\titleformat{\part}[display]{\center\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
%                            {\partname\ \thepart}{20pt}{\Huge} 
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{part}[0pt]{}{\Large\bfseries Part \thecontentslabel\\*}
                           {\Large\bfseries Unnumbered Part\\*}{}[]
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{}{Chapter \thecontentslabel\\*}
                              {Unnumbered Chapter\\*}{}[]
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \part{The first part}
  \chapter{The first chapter}
\end{document}
```